# 'Java Deployment' allows 'auto proxy(PAC/WPAD)', what about the JRE?

Tags: java, proxy, java-8, java-web-start, pac

Both files below are part of a JAVA installation and contain proxy settings

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties
(also reflected in the RegKey: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\JavaSoft\DeploymentProperties)

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\net.properties
```

Our application is executed both by using
- JRE(located inside our software)
- Java Webstart(which selects a System installed JRE).

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/properties.html) is says that  'Deployment.properties' (set via the Java Control Panel) can be configured for 'automatic Proxy Detection' (PAC/WPAD). *I'm asuming this file applies to the Webstart download and start part only.*

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html) it doesn't look like the 'net.properties'  file can't do anything with PAC/WPAD. *I'm asuming this file applies to the JRE*

I'd like my application to use 'proxy auto detection', but as far as i know the JRE is not able to use automatic detection settings(PAC/WPAD) and is only able to use static settings.

Because system properties '-Dhttp.proxyHost' etc are not accepted in JNLP[(source)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html) because they're classified 'insecure'. I must be wrong in my assumptions somewhere.

Do the applications started by webstart really have the priviledge of 'proxy autodetection' which locally started apps don't have?